# Second camera doesn't render 3D modle in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm creating an AR app by Unity and Vuforia. In my scene I have two Cameras. The first camera is `ARCamera` and the second one is `SecondCamera`. The second `Camera` get its rotation and position from AR camera. It just moves and rotates smoother than AR camera.

I have a cube as a child of `ImageTarget`. I want to render this cube just by the second camera. I defined a new layer as `ARCamIgnoreLayer` and set Culling Mask of the second camera to it. Also, I unchecked `ARCamIgnoreLayer` from AR camera's Culling Mask field.
Also, I added a `RenderTexture` to `target texture` field of the second camera. I set this render texture as `main texture` of a material of a plane. In this manner, I projected everything which the second camera can see on this plane.

I placed this plane between Vuforia's `BackgroundPlane` and AR Camera. This way finally I can see something which AR camera is rendered in the background and something which the second camera is rendered in foreground in `game` window (game view).

Now I have two problems. Dissolving one means dissolving the other.

1. Theoretically render of these two cameras must be same; because I set `field of view` of the second camera to the same number as AR camera. Also, as I said, these two cameras have the same position and rotation. But their renders aren't matching. I can't understand what's wrong with it.
2. To prevent the first problem, I copied the `Camera` component and its values from the AR camera and pasted it to the second camera. I wanted to be sure that all fields of the `Camera` component of the second camera have the same values as all fields of camera component of AR camera. Then I changed some values by a script at runtime (some things like culling mask etc). Now the second camera doesn't render anything. It just returns a solid color. I don't know what's wrong with this too.

Here are the codes:

## 1:

```
void CreateSecondCam()
{
    CopyComponent(_aRCam.GetComponent<Camera>(), gameObject);

}



T CopyComponent<T>(T original, GameObject destination) where T : Component
{
    System.Type type = original.GetType();
    var dst = destination.GetComponent(type) as T;
    if (!dst) dst = destination.AddComponent(type) as T;
    var fields = type.GetFields();
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (field.IsStatic) continue;
        field.SetValue(dst, field.GetValue(original));
    }
    var props = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (!prop.CanWrite || prop.Name == "name") continue;
        prop.SetValue(dst, prop.GetValue(original, null), null);
    }
    return dst as T;
}
```

This part of my script copy camera component from AR camera and paste it to second camera.

## 2:

```
void AssignSomeValues()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().targetTexture = _chromaKeyRenderTexrture;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = _defaultCameraBackgroundColor;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().cullingMask = 9 << 8;
    }
```

This function assign some values to some fields of camera component of second camera.

## 3:

```
void Update()
{
    gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, _aRCam.transform.position, _softness * Time.deltaTime);
    gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(gameObject.transform.rotation, _aRCam.transform.rotation, _softness * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I had moved and rotated second camera base on AR camera position and rotation in `Update` function.

Here are the screenshots:

## 1:

AR camera

[image: AR camera inspector]

## 2:

second camera

[image: second camera inspector]

## 3:

Cube

[image: cube inspector]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I Changed the `Depth` of my AR camera. I set depth of AR camera to -10. Now the second camera view port appears in front of AR camera view port. It works perfectly.